# I want to show only the first post title for each category in Gatsbyjs allWpCategory, but it's not working as I expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, components, react-props

I want to show only **first post title** for each category in **Gatsbyjs** **`allWpCategory`**, but it's not working as I expected. **`${post[0].title`** not work in loop, but **`${post.title}`** return all the post title in each category is there any other way to do it?

Here is my code

```
const { allWpCategory : data } = myCategoryQuery();
{data.edges.map(category => {
return (
                <div key={category.node.id}>
                       {category.node.name}

                       {category.node.posts.nodes.map(post => {
                            return (
                                <div key={post.id}>{`${post[0].title}`}</div>
                            )
                       })}
                       
                </div>
            )
}
```

Here is the Query hook:

```
export const myCategoryQuery = () => {
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query AllCategoryQuery {
        allWpCategory(limit: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
              posts {
                nodes {
                  title
                  uri
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `)
```

Comment: What do you get when you log out `category.node.posts.nodes` (before mapping over it)?

Comment: @Boguz thanks for coming to help! before mapping I was getting `category.node.posts.nodes[0] is undefined`. But it was working when I loop it with `post.title`. So I'm getting the whole list of title under each category, but I need the 1 post title in each category. Don't know where is the missing.

Comment: what about just `category`? are you getting anything there?

Comment: @Boguz Yes, category is working fine `{category.node.name}`

Comment: @Boguz And `category.node.posts.nodes` returns nothing. Any help?

Comment: could you post on your question what you get from `console.log(category)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249817/discussion-between-devbuddy-and-boguz).

Answer (score 1):

inside your map function you can't use `post[0]`, instead you can simply use `post`, like in this example:

```js
const posts = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Title one"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Title two"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Title three"
  },
];

posts.map((post) => {
  console.log(`${post.id}: ${post.title}`);
})
```

There is some good information and examples about the `map` function [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)